# How to make text align with input?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How to make `kbps` to be inline with input box? Which mean, `kbps` will be next to input box. Not like image below.

[image]

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <label class="form-control-label">New Bandwidth (kbps):</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type='number' style='display:inline;'><span>kbps</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add more clarity. it is aligned (to the left), as far as I can see.

Comment: what is the actual issue here ?

Comment: I want kbps to be after input box

Comment: use `<br>` to break the line.

Comment: I don't want New Line. But Inline.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
     <label class="form-control-label">New Bandwidth (kbps):</label> 
     <input type='number' style='display:inline-block;'><span>kbps</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to separate label and input in different column. not in 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

After done customization then I found what I want.
Maybe this is not the best practice.

[image]

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <label class="form-control-label">New Bandwidth:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 pl-3 pr-0">
        <input type='number'>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 pd-0 ml-2">
        <span>kbps</span>
    </div>
</div>
```